# Can I set visual studio 2005 command line switches in my code (ie through pragma/define)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I know that you can provide a command line or add switches in your project properties but can you do that from source file? I need to set certain switches for certain source files without going into project properties and manually doing it everytime. So maybe you can do it with preprocessors from C++ source file?

Comment: Some things can be done using `#pragma`s and `#define`s. What settings do you have in mind?

Comment: Are you trying to implement macros for VS or to have file-specific compiler settings? In the latter case, you can change the properties of single files, and probably there are also [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)s for them

Comment: For example: I would like to disable language extensions with `/Za` switch.

Answer (score 0):

There're some #pragma's that can, for example, alter code generation/optimization for a block of code, but I think that's pretty limited thing.

Answer (score 0):

First: Compilation/linking do not execute your C++ code. So you can't write a C++ piece'o code and make decision (to change some project settings of THIS project) based on some C++ conditions (like if/else/...).

`#pragma` and `#defines` are pre-processor directives as you already know. Though compiler understands `#pragmas`, programming capability is limited and usually compiler specific.

A common use of these is to make the code platform independent.

To answer your original question "how do I modify the project properties progrmatically (not manuall)?": You can write "code" using `#pragmas` & `#defines` (even conditional ones) in your code to control various settings. Usually support is compiler-vendor specific, so your code will most probably not be portable (across compilers) unless you're careful.

On my GCC, I always found c++config.h a good example of various cpp directive. On my windows PC it's installed in `X:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c++config.h`

To find out supported cpp directives, RTM of your compiler.

---

The other option obviously is to write shell/perl/... script to make modifications to the project settings/Makefiles. I recommend that compared to getting yourself tangled in cpp directives. :)

Of course this option would change the settings **before** compilation and not **during**. But if that's not a prob for you, go with this rather than cpp directives.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, `#pragma` statements are very vendor specific. For Visual Studio 2005, take a look here for the supported `#pragma` statements: [Pragma Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

I would also with thekashyap regarding writing a script to modify the project settings for each file for the following reasons:

- In the event that you have to add or change a setting, there is a *single* place to modify.

  Because there is only one place to look, future maintainers know where to find special settings for a given file. They won't be surprised by something set manually that is hidden deep within the project settings dialogs.